# WPF MVVM - Анимация перехода между представлениями

Tags: wpf, анимация, mvvm, mvvm-light

Разрабатываю проект на WPF с использованием паттерна MVVM. Использую MVVM Light. Каким образом возможно реализовать анимацию переходов от одного представления к другому? К примеру, плавное "затухание" одного и появление другого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю как это делается в MVVM Light, я обычно определяю StoryBoard внутри нужного элемента c нужной анимацией, привязываю триггер анимации к нужному свойству элемента, через который реализован переход (скажем, Button.IsPressed). Все работает.
Здесь поподробнее
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms742868(v=vs.110).aspx